# controls in notification center today widget have their colours inverted

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, today-extension

I'm building an app extension for the Today section of the Notification Centre in OSX. My problem is that when I add controls like NSTableView or NSDatePicker their colours get inverted. NSTextField and NSButton seem to get inverted to, but they look great when they do. However, NSTableView does not look good, and I'd like it to display like it does in a normal window.

I don't have enough reputation to post an image apparently, so you'll have to checkout this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nH0.png) to see what I mean.

I've tired fixing this programmatically in swift by setting the NSTableView's appearence property but that doesn't seem to fix my problem.

```
tableView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?